# Resize image propotionaly image to insert a4 page

Tags: java, image-processing, ms-word, apache-poi

How to resize image proptional and for pretty insert to word document with apache POI. But if i insert image wirth orignal size image insert in original size.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply fixed with formula

> original height / original width x new width = new height

[Source](http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/aspect_ratio/)